# Copy files from one directory to another, ignoring files where the destination's file has been modified in the last hour?

Tags: centos, command-line, rsync, file-copy

Attempting to discover a command to copy files if the destination's (not source's) file has not been modified in the last hour.

Comment: There isn't a direct one. Could you modify your requirement to copy files only if the source is newer (has been modified more recently) than the target?

Comment: Sadly not. Is it possible to move files that have been modified in the last hour? If that is the case, I could do that, copy all the files then move the moved files back into their original location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know of no command that will precisely match your requirement. Something like this should work (remove the `--dry-run` when you're sure you're happy with the result; replace the `--verbose` with `--quiet` if you want it to run more silently):

```
src=/path/to/source
dst=/path/to/target

comm -z -23 \
        <(find "$src" -type f -printf '%P\0' | sort -z) \
        <(find "$dst" -type f -mmin -60 -printf '%P\0' | sort -z) |
    rsync --dry-run --verbose --archive --from0 --files-from - "$src" "$dst"
```

It assumes relatively recent utilities that understand how to handle NUL-terminated lines. If necessary, and provided that you can guarantee that no filenames contain newlines, you could remove the three `-z` flags and `rsync`'s `--from0` and replace the `\0` in the `find` commands with `\n`.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you! Not sure if this works yet, will give it a go when this is required.

Answer (score 0):

If all your copies are to existing files, you can look at it the other way: overwrite local files if they are older than one hour. So, with the **destination** directory as the working directory:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -mmin +60 -exec cp /source/directory/{} . \;
```

where:

- `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -mmin +60` finds the local files that are over an hour old
- `-exec cp /source/directory/{} . \;` overwrites them with their namesake from `/source/directory`

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a shot if roaima's answer doesn't work.